# AWS Athena Decimal

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I'm creating a new external table in AWS Athena. When I try to create a `decimal(9,2)` variable, the creation of the table is fine, but when I try to `SELECT`, I get the following error:

```
GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveDecimal
```

Example of my DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MY_DB`.`MY_NEW_TABLE` (
  `event_id` bigint
  ,`time_stamp` string
  ,`amount` decimal(9,2)
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `year` smallint
  ,`month` tinyint
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'separatorChar' = ','
  ,'quoteChar' = '"'
  ,'escapeChar' = '\\'
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://<BUCKETNAME>/<SUBFOLDER>/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'classification' = 'csv'
    ,'skip.header.line.count' = '1'
);
```

If I define `amount` as a `float`, it works, and I can later `CAST()` it to a `decimal(9,2)` as I want, but I would prefer to have it in the table structure directly.

Comment: Not sure which version of hive AWS Athena use but this is working in latest Apache Hive(v4) using hdfs

Comment: `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfs -cat /user/hive/newtest_csv/newtest_csv_decml.scv`

"1","2022-12-23 09:35:58.21245","0.471032"
"2","2022-12-23 09:35:58.21245","0.942063"
"3","2022-12-23 09:35:58.21245","1.413095"
"4","2022-12-23 09:35:58.21245","1.884126"
`
`select * from newtest_csv;`
`| newtest_csv.event_id  |   newtest_csv.time_stamp   | newtest_csv.amount  |

| 1                     | 2022-12-23 09:35:58.21245  | 0.471032            |
| 2                     | 2022-12-23 09:35:58.21245  | 0.942063            |
...`

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newtest_csv` (
  `event_id` bigint
  ,`time_stamp` string
  ,`amount` decimal(9,2)
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'separatorChar' = ','
  ,'quoteChar' = '"'
  ,'escapeChar' = '\\'
) location '/user/hive/newtest_csv';